# No team project error during vss migrate to devops

Tags: migration, devops, visual-sourcesafe

Struggling to fix this error. We are migrating a vss2005 db to devops.

The vss has a single project named devloptool.

In devops, we created a project with name devloptool too.

We use the tool mentioned in
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.risual.com/2020/01/migrating-from-vss-to-azure-devops/&ved=2ahUKEwj3y5Gw56f0AhUzKX0KHWTlAgcQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1qWTihWY0C73zgMmz6yHmr

During the migration, the tool threw error of
Team project "$developtool\developtool" not found.

In stead of pushing all files directly to $develop folder, not sure why the migration tool trying to push them to $developtool\developtool

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by wrong repository type.
To use the migration tool, the target must be a tfvc repository while I had git.